# Authentication in Asp.Net MVC and Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to combine OpenId authentication and bearer token authentication through the use of IdentityServer.

My project is an Asp.net MVC project, with a web api component. I would like to use OpenId authentication for the standard MVC controllers, and bearer token authentication for the web api component.

My front end is written in Angularjs, and calls web api methods through the $http service to populate the UI.

I am having a problem setting up the authentication workflow.

My thoughts initially were to try to execute the following algorithm:

1. User requests some web api method from the server through an ajax call ($http)
2. App detects the user is not authenticated and bearer token is not present in request header, redirects to MVC controller method to retrieve the bearer token.
3. Since the user is not authenticated, the server will redirect to the IdentityServer default login page.
4. Once the user is logged in, the server automatically redirects back to the bearer token method to get a bearer token
5. The generated bearer token is somehow returned to the client.

However my algorithm breaks down at step 3. I am trying to implement step 2 by using an httpinterceptor to inspect outgoing request to determine if a bearer token is present.

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {

        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }
        else {
         $location.path('/Authentication/BearerToken');
        }

        return config;
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/Authentication/BearerToken');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;}]);
```

If the token is not present, I exit the SPA and redirect to the bearer token MVC method.

This will successfully redirect to the login page, however once I log in, I am returned a bearer token in JSON directly on the page, since I am now outside of the Ajax call.

So my question is

**could you please provide me with alternate ideas (and an outline of an implementation) on how to combine these two modes of authentication into one workflow?**

Perhaps there is a way to customize IdentityServer to do what I want?

My basic requirement is that an unauthenticated user on my SPA angularjs app is redirected to the default IdentityServer login page, and once logged in, that the initial request be fulfilled.

Thanks in advance!

Just in case you are curious, my IdentityServer setup is as follows. The authentication service is in a separate project from the web application. Each has it's own Startup.cs file.

The MVC Startup.cs file

```
 public class Startup
{
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
         AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
         JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

         app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
         {
             AuthenticationType = "Cookies",                
         });

         var openIdConfig = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
         {
             Authority = "https://localhost:44301/identity",
             ClientId = "baseballStats",
             Scope = "openid profile roles baseballStatsApi",
             RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
             ResponseType = "id_token token",
             SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",                 
             UseTokenLifetime = false,
             Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
             {
                 SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                 {
                     var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                                  new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                                  n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                     var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();

                     // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                     var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                         Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                         Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                     userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(c => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(c.Item1, c.Item2)));

                     // keep the id_token for logout
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                     // add access token for sample API
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                     // keep track of access token expiration
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

                     // add some other app specific claim
                     nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                     n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                         nid,
                         n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);                         
                 }
             }
         };

         app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConfig);

         app.UseResourceAuthorization(new AuthorizationManager());

         app.Map("/api", inner =>
         {
             var bearerTokenOptions = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 Authority = "https://localhost:44301/identity",
                 RequiredScopes = new[] { "baseballStatsApi" }                     
             };

             inner.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(bearerTokenOptions);
             var config = new HttpConfiguration();
             config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
             inner.UseWebApi(config);
         });                                                 
     }
}
```

The IdentityServer Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var policy = new System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyOrigin = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true,
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            SupportsCredentials = true
        };

        //policy.ExposedHeaders.Add("location: http://location.com");
        policy.Headers.Add("location: testing");
        app.UseCors(new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(policy)
            }
        });
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "Embedded IdentityServer",
                SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

                Factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
                    users: Users.Get(),
                    clients: Clients.Get(),
                    scopes: Scopes.Get())
            });
        });            
    }

    X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            string.Format(@"{0}\bin\Configuration\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have made some progress in redirecting to the Login page. The issue I was having is that the initial call to the web api was being redirected by IdentityServer with a status code of 302. This meant that I could not get access to the Location header which contains the url I want to redirect to. So instead, I added some owin middleware to check the status code, and if a 302, return a 401 instead (I need to also check that the call is Ajax but have not yet implemented this).

```
app.Use(async (environment, next) =>
         {
             await next();

             if (environment.Response.StatusCode == 302)
             {
                 environment.Response.StatusCode = 401;
             }                 
         });
```

This then gives me access to the Location header on the client side, and I can redirect, like so:

```
getPlayerList: function (queryParameters) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('api/pitchingstats/GetFilteredPlayers', {
            skip: queryParameters.skip,
            take: queryParameters.take,
            orderby: queryParameters.orderby,
            sortdirection: queryParameters.sortdirection,
            filter: queryParameters.filter
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                               
            if (status === 401) {
               window.location = headers().location;
            }
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(status);
        });
```

I know it's a hack, but it's the only way I can make my approach work currently. By all means feel free to suggest other methods.

Comment: there is an entire blog series dedicated to the task you are trying to accomplish at http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know if I can adapt this method to what I am trying to do, particularly as the author is not using IdentityServer.

Comment: It seems the author uses a custom login page accessed directly through angularjs. I would prefer not to do this, so I'm not sure how much of his angular implementation will be useful to me.

Comment: I am still looking for some information on IdentityServer specifically, and the workflow that is used for this technology